# Exporting multiple sheets to PDF and getting run time error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting RunTime error of '(2147024773)8007007b' everytime I execute the macro, I don't know what I have done wrong. Any hints on how to fix this?

```
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
Sheets("Main_Page").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A01:F30").Select
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A01:B6").Select

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: There is no Value stored in strFilename. You need to set some name before running the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you creating the variable and assigning a value to it you can try this. Also try avoiding select and activate.

```
Sub SaveMultipleSheetsAsPDF()
Dim strFilename As String
Dim sht1 As Range
Dim sht3 As Range

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Main_Page").Range("A1:F30")
Set sht3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B6")
strFilename = "mySheets"


sht1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

sht3.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: @SolarMike You are right he needs to quality the sheets rathar than using select and activate all over the place. updated code to match.